# Some Text of website page on Iphone Safari become invisible

Tags: css, html

I have designed and developed WordPress theme from scratch. Now after completion of website i am having an issue.

On iphone safari browser page content become invisible but working perfectly on all the screens, Mobile, tablet and laptop.

Iphone View of About Page

[image]

Android View of About Page

[image]

Comment: Which elements? Which iPhone/Safari version?

Comment: I have tested on Iphone 4, 5 & 6. I am also having problem on other browsers too on iphone.

Comment: And what elements are missing? Make screenshots, how it looks, how it is supposed to look, how it looks on other devices. Then check your CSS carefully, I know firefox & chrome support debug on mobile phones, not sure about safari

Comment: Hello kero, i have updated screenshots of android and iphone.

Comment: Here is url of above mention screenshots page: canofbananas.com/wordpress/about/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Problem was strange because there was no html or css issue.

The Problem is solved now. The problem was due to the font `ttf, eot, woff` files. I changed the font of website and my website started working perfectly.